# ¿ Existe alguna forma de ocultar los botones de cerrar , minimizar, maximizar y la barra de estado en Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Lo que quiero es crear una splash screen o pantalla de carga pero no tengo idea de como ocultar la barra en tkinter alguien que me ayude

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si no mal recuerdo se usa:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.attributes('-type', 'splash')
app.mainloop()
```

También puedes esconder el "title bar" con `root.overrideredirect(True)`

Comment: Ayúdanos a conservar la calidad en el sitio, respondiendo preguntas realizadas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Respondí porque fue una pregunta valida, que tu criterio sea distinto, lo respeto. Sin embargo, no está pidiendo que le hagan su trabajo, por eso me atreví a responder.

Comment: Hola @Roy, veo que hasta el día de hoy tampoco has realizado el tour del sitio, es importante saber como deben plantear los usuarios sus preguntas para no contribuir a agregar contenido de baja calidad al sitio. En ocasiones este tipo de preguntas solo sonde ayuda para el que pregunta pero no para la comunidad que es lo que se busca.

Comment: @Jorgesys Entonces sólo debo respoder preguntas que bajo tu criterio ¿sólo ayuden a la comunidad y no a quién pregunta? Se supone que el fin del stackoverflow es crear una base de conocimientos dando diversas soluciones a distintos problemas, que si pones un enlace está mal, y si respondes preguntas pobres también está mal. En definitiva ya no responderé nada.

Comment: **Se sugiere responder preguntas bajo el criterio definido en el sitio, revisa [ask]**. Si deseas responder todas es bajo tu criterio, pero como vuelvo a mencionar contribuyes a la baja calidad del sitio.

Comment: @Jorgesys "Se sugiere" más no se obliga. No se si entiendas la definición de "sugerir". Por eso la comunidad en inglés es más grande, y la comunidad en español tiene menos respuestas, debido a que desaniman la colaboración. No responderé a más preguntas, prefiero la comunidad en inglés.

Comment: @Jorgesys entonces él debió leer el "cómo preguntar", hay preguntas que por su contexto son validas como la presente, pero aquella, vino sin investigar, sólo pegó su código xml y tampoco veo muy activa la comunidad respondiendo las preguntas. Y a mi me dan puntuación negativa por incitarlo a investigar, tampoco es correcto hacerles su chamba.

Comment: Tienes razón @Roy el debió revisar ese enlace, lo que regularmente hacemos antes de responder sugerirles agregar más información a su pregunta, sucede en ocasiones (a mi me sucedia) que lo que respondemos no es lo que requería la persona que pregunta :-( .